# Magento upgrade from 2.2.3 to 2.3.0 just blew Cheeze balls .. help

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade, mariadb

just finshed updating composer update,

`bin/magento setup:upgrade`
Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:

```
/home/pricesplitters/public_html/generated/code/Composer
/home/pricesplitters/public_html/generated/code/MSP
/home/pricesplitters/public_html/generated/code/Magento
/home/pricesplitters/public_html/generated/code/Symfony
```

The directory `/home/pricesplitters/public_html/generated/metadata/` doesn't exist - skipping cleanup
Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-14dec WHERE
>   `Non_unique` = 1' at line 1, query was: SHOW INDEXES FROM
>   mp_vendor_registration_assign_group_bk-14dec WHERE `Non_unique` = 1

Boom .. cheezeballs.

Comment: have double check your database connection?

Comment: Yes its running, there are 2 other Magento2 sites on the server. This was the only one that needed to be upgraded.

Comment: I took a look for the error and found it here.


grep: update/vendor/symfony: Is a directory
grep: update/vendor/theseer: Is a directory
grep: update/vendor/webmozart: Is a directory
var/backups/1553221974_db.sql:-- Table structure for table `mp_vendor_registration_assign_group_bk-14dec`
var/backups/1553221974_db.sql:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mp_vendor_registration_assign_group_bk-14dec`;
var/backups/1553221974_db.sql:CREATE TABLE `mp_vendor_registration_assign_group_bk-14dec` (
var/backups/1553221974_db.sql:-- Dumping data for table `mp_vendor_registration_assign_group_bk-14dec`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151649)

Comment: I went and found the Table and removed it.   It resolved the error.  The next error.

 php bin/magento setup:di:compile
In ErrorHandler.php line 61:
  Warning: Declaration of Webkul\Xtremo\Block\Html\Topmenu::_getHtml(Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree, $childrenWrapClass, $limit, $colBrakes
   = Array) should be compatible with Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu::_getHtml(Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree, $childrenWrapClass, $limit
  , array $colBrakes = Array) in /home/pricesplitters/public_html/app/code/Webkul/Xtremo/Block/Html/Topmenu.php on line 177
setup:di:compile